# subprocess.communicate parsing err and out

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm trying to launch git commands via python , and parse their results.
For example:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["git","checkout","master"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)    
out,err = p.communicate()
```

**Question is:** why when I print out I get nothing and when I print `err` I get things that should be on `out` variable, such as: `Switched to branch 'master'` or
`Already on 'master'`.

I mean that I get the `out` content in `err` and `err` content in `out`, why is that?

Comment: According to [git source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/checkout.c#L674) _Already on 'branch_name'_ is printed to stderr. Same goes to _ Switched to branch..._ message.  I bet rest of output is also in correct place.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski: Thanks, 1.Do you have any idea why it is done like that?
2.How can I know for each git command which output is printed to stderr and which to stdout, is there some table that summarize this?